# Android OS back button takes me back to Expo projects screen

Tags: android, react-navigation, expo

Firstly, I have a React Native app built using Expo and utilising React Navigation for routing.

I'm using a SwitchNavigator to switch between two stack navigators which represent my authorisation workflow (my screens before I've logged in) and my app workflow (the screens after I've logged in) and it looks something like this.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Second: SecondScreen, HouseDetail: HouseDetailScreen, Camera: CameraScreen}
);
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: LoginScreen }
);

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'


  }
);
```

My problem is that the behaviour of the back button in Android does not behave properly.

Here is a scenario. I've just logged in, and I'm in the App stack's HomeScreen page. I will navigate to the SecondScreen using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Second')
```

At this point, I would imagine that if I hit the back button, I should go back to the HomeScreen.

However, when I press the back button (the one built into the OS), I get taken out of my app and into the Expo projects list.

If I run this.props.navigation.goBack() though, then it works as expected and I'm back at the home screen.

Why is this happening? Is this an Expo thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so this was hours of time I'll never get back.

Turns out this is an issue with the latest version of Firebase.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1603

The solution is to downgrade to 5.0.3 and this worked for me.