# Expo react navigation android back button

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I've been developing a react native app on expo, the navigation was working in the beginning, after awhile the app start to exit when android button was pressed.

I used the expo starter navigation sample, i removed the `createSwitchNaviagtor` and replaced it with `createStackNavigator`, the app shows the header back arrow but still when the back button is pressed the app exits.

these are the code snippets.

> **Package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "expo": "29.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.4.2",
    "native-base": "^2.8.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^2.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "29.0.0"
  }
}
```

> **AppNavigator**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Main tab
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
// Screens
import SuppliersScreen from '../screens/suppliers/SuppliersScreen'
import SupplierScreen from '../screens/supplier/SupplierScreen'
import ItemScreen from '../screens/item/ItemScreen'
import BasketScreen from '../screens/basket/BasketScreen'
import OrderScreen from '../screens/order/OrderScreen'
import EditProfileScreen from '../screens/editProfile/EditProfileScreen'
import AboutScreen from '../screens/about/AboutScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../screens/login/LoginScreen';
import SignupScreen from '../screens/signup/SignupScreen';
import PasswordResetScreen from '../screens/passwordReset/PassWordReset';
import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/categories/CategoriesScreen';

const SuppliersStack = createStackNavigator({
  Suppliers: SuppliersScreen,
});
const SupplierStack = createStackNavigator({
  Supplier: SupplierScreen,
});

const ItemStack = createStackNavigator({
  Item: ItemScreen,
});

const BasketStack = createStackNavigator({
  Basket: BasketScreen,
});

const OrderStack = createStackNavigator({
  Order: OrderScreen,
});

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
});

const SignupStack = createStackNavigator({
  Signup: SignupScreen,
});

const PasswordResetStack = createStackNavigator({
  PasswordReset: PasswordResetScreen,
});

const EditProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  EditProfile: EditProfileScreen,
});

const AboutStack = createStackNavigator({
  About: AboutScreen,
});

export default createStackNavigator({
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  Suppliers: SuppliersStack,
  Supplier: SupplierStack,
  Item: ItemStack,
  Basket: BasketStack,
  Order: OrderStack,
  EditProfile: EditProfileStack,
  About: AboutStack,
  Login: LoginStack,
  Signup: SignupStack,
  PasswordReset: PasswordResetStack
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Main'
  });
```

> **MainTabNavigator**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/home/HomeScreen/';
import ProfileScreen from '../screens/profile/ProfileScreen';
import OrdersScreen from '../screens/orders/OrdersScreen'

// Home screen
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});
HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-home'
      }
    />
  ),
};
// Orders Screen
const OrdersStack = createStackNavigator({
  Orders: OrdersScreen,
});
OrdersStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Orders',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-reorder${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-reorder'}
    />
  ),
};

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
});
ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-cog` : 'md-cog'}
    />
  ),
};
// Main Bottom Tab Navigation
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  OrdersStack,
  ProfileStack,
});
```

> **App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, NetInfo, YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import { Root } from "native-base";
import _ from 'lodash';
// //import firebase

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Setting a timer']);
const _console = _.clone(console);
console.warn = message => {
  if (message.indexOf('Setting a timer') <= -1) {
    _console.warn(message);
  }
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoadingComplete: false,
    };

  }


  async componentWillMount() {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    });


  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <Root>
            <AppNavigator />
          </Root>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
        require('./assets/images/robot-prod.png'),
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
        ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
        // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
        // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
        'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
      }),
    ]);
  };

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error
    // reporting service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoadingComplete: true });
  };
}
```

Thank you

**UPDATED**

```js
export default createStackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainTabNavigator
  },
  Suppliers: {
    screen: SuppliersScreen
  },
  Supplier: {
    screen: SupplierScreen
  },
  Item: {
    screen: ItemScreen
  },
  Basket: {
    screen: BasketScreen
  },
  Order: {
    screen: OrderScreen
  },
  EditProfile: {
    screen: EditProfileScreen
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutScreen
  },
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen
  },
  Signup: {
    screen: SignupScreen
  },
  PasswordReset: {
    screen: PasswordResetScreen
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Main'
  });
```

That's the other way i tried too

Comment: Well the problem is that you’re creating so many StackNavigators and then putting them all under one StackNavigator. Is there a reason why you are unable to just simply create one single StackNavigator to hold the path for all your screens?

Comment: @Harrison there's no specific reason, but i tried putting them in one stack navigator, and i was still getting the same effect,

Comment: Abdiqadir Oscan can I see the code for that please

Comment: @Harrison i updated the question and the app still exists.

Comment: Okay, so when the app exits are you able to retrieve any kind of error code, say, from the debug console? Your `react-navigation` implementation seems to be right.

Comment: @Harrison the app exits with no error, just minimised, similar to home button behaviour

Comment: Any alternative solutions for this question?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to this problem, i found solutions in [Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529293/android-os-back-button-takes-me-back-to-expo-projects-screen).
this solution worked [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51541571/10445040)